# Redmine 3.3.x : Plugin for requesting and validating congestions (leaves)

Tags: redmine, bitnami, redmine-plugins

I working on Redmine for RH management systems ;
I'm looking for a free plugin which affor an approbal system of asking for leaves (request) and leaves accepting or refusing  :

Example : 
the employee fills a Leave request  **->** his team Leader / boss may validate it or refuse it

1. Leaves requesting
2. Leaves validating
3. calender overviewing

Of course that must be compatible with the lastest Redmine release 3.3.x

**any suggestions ??**

Comment: Please explain what you mean by congestions and congestions validation and requestions

Comment: ok you may read it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use issues for managing the leaves. you can customize the issues form using plugins such as issue templates: http://www.redmine.org/plugins/issue_templates.

You can display the issues on a calendar using a plugin such as: http://www.redmine.org/plugins/mega_calendar

Another useful plugin is: http://www.redmine.org/plugins/service_desk